# Passwords wont set

Tags: python, django

I have made a custom user model and manager however I cannot get passwords to save in my registration form. No errors are shown but when I look in the admin panel it says "No password set.". Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in my code? Cheers

Models -

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password1, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password1)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('staff status', default=False,
        help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True,
        help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

Forms -

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Both Passwords must match!")
```

Error from suggestion -

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000003D60668>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\Other folders\Desktop\Student Job Search\code\opus_jobs_project\profiles\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from opus_login.models import User
  File "D:\Other folders\Desktop\Student Job Search\code\opus_jobs_project\opus_login\models.py", line 43, in <module>
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 223, in __new__
    'base class %r' % (field.name, name, base.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'password' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractBaseUser'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually set password for a user, you'll need to call the `set_password` method. First, create a `save` method in `UserForm` class.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your code ...
    # ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```